# How to disable one legend before render fusion chart

Tags: javascript, charts, fusioncharts

I have 3 legends in the 2D bar chart and I need to disable one of them when show them to the user at first time, disable means I want to show the legend button but hide the bars so that user can click the legend button to show the bars later.

Anybody has answer?

Answer (score 0):

By default, FusionCharts renders data sets in enabled mode. So, it is not possible to hide few data sets while the chart renders initially.